# The startScanFromFragment method of Scan Kit cannot be called as expected

Tags: android, zxing, barcode-scanner, huawei-mobile-services

I have developed a logistics app, which needs to scan barcodes on parcels frequently. I've tried integrating ZXing to implement the barcode scanning function, but it cannot recognize barcodes accurately in some scenarios including strong light, bending, and deformation... Now, I've integrated HUAWEI Scan Kit, but its **startScanFromFragment(Fragment f, int code, HmsSanAnalyzerOptions o)** method does not work. Because **fragment** that I'm using inherits from **androidx.fragment.app.** What should I do? Plz give me some points.

Comment: Did you implement simultaneous scanning?

Comment: @Mike-mei Sure. Plz refer to this XDA article [Comparative Analysis of Zxing and HUAWEI Scan Kit](https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/huawei-developers/comparative-analysis-zxing-huawei-scan-t4132603)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **fragment** parameter in **startScanFromFragment** is **android.native.fragment**. However, the **android.native.fragment** API is about to be deprecated and will not be included in the Scan Kit API Reference. You are advised to use the **startScan(Activity a, int code, HmsSanAnalyzerOptions o)** method for barcode scanning.

In addition, Scan Kit provides four integration modes: Default View, Customized View, Bitmap, and MultiProcessor. Scan Kit is able to accurately and quickly scan barcodes from a long distance, in challenging scenarios, and no matter how the barcode is oriented.
To learn more, please visit [HUAWEI Scan Kit](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/service-introduction-0000001050041994).

Answer (score 0):

I am unaware of the use of Fragments with the Scan Kit. It would be very nice to have some context because I could not find any documentation about it.

However, the [Scan Kit](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/hms/huawei-scankit) should be exactly what you are looking for your use case. To my knowledge there are three different ways on how to implement it. The [Default View Mode](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/codelab/ScanKit-DefaultView/index.html#0) is the easiest implementation, with the [Customized View Mode](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/codelab/ScanKit/index.html#0) you are able to change the UI of the scanning process and the [Bitmap Mode](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/codelab/ScanKit-BitmapMode/index.html#0) lets you completely customize the scanning process.

My assumption is that either the Default or Customized View Mode will be sufficient for your logistics app.

> What should I do? Plz give me some points.

Above I linked you all the available Codelabs for the Scan Kit as they give you a nice step by step guide on how to integrate its different modes. If you need a Kotlin version of the guide, you can find them on [this](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/community/codelabs) page next to Java versions.